# Getting Error while upgrading Sonar to 5.5 Version and failing to Start

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, findbugs

I recently upgraded my Sonar Version to 5.5 and all the compatible plugins with it.

Here are the versions of the plugins installed:-

sonar-ldap-plugin-1.5.1.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.13.jar
sonar-java-plugin-3.14.jar
sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.1.jar
sonar-php-plugin-2.8.jar
**sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar**

If I use sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar, the Sonar is not getting Up and throwing below error :-

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The rule 'EC_INCOMPATIBLE_ARRAY_COMPARE' of repository 'findbugs' is declared several times**

If I downgrade the Jar to sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.jar it works but fails to analyse the Project and throws below error :-

**An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar**

I have tried the versions - 3.3,3.3.1 and 3.3.2

Any Help ?

Comment: I have the same problem after downgrading to version 3.3 from version 3.4.3. You should try to upgrade to version 3.4.3.

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux Thanks for the solution but I can't downgrade/Upgrade the version as it is something critical for our project.
Any other option to resolve this ?

Comment: you should find the rule EC_INCOMPATIBLE_ARRAY_COMPARE in your repository into the Sonar database and removing one of them I suppose. I don't remember exactly the context of this error since it is a bit old but it should work.

Comment: okay. Thanks for the support. Will try this as well